# Using Soundcloud Python library in Google App Engine - what files do I need to move?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pip, soundcloud

I want to use the soundcloud python library in a web app I am developing in Google App Engine.   However, I can't find any file called "soundcloud.py" in the soundcloud library files I downloaded.  When using pip install it works fine on my local computer.

What files exactly do I need to move - or what exact steps do I need to take - in order to be able to "import soundcloud" within Google App Engine.

I already tried moving all the *.py files into my main app directory, but still got this error:
import soundcloud
ImportError: No module named soundcloud

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your `soundcloud` external library into your App Package. Where exactly to place them within your application is fairly dependant on frameworks your application uses, but the `soundcloud` must exist on your PYTHONPATH somewhere.

Also, `soundcloud` isn't a solitary library. You'll also need [fudge](http://farmdev.com/projects/fudge/) and `simplejson` (Included in appengine since 1.4.2). Just grab both package folders from your local pip install, and stick em somewhere in your application that's already loaded in your path.

To see where your local installed pip folders are, just fake that you're uninstalling one of the packages. On my machine, this looks like this:

```
sparker% sudo pip uninstall fudge
Password:
Uninstalling fudge:
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fudge
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fudge-1.0.3-py2.7.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)? n
```

You only need to grab the `fudge` folder to include in your application, but I'd take both. It's always nice later to know which version of applications you're bundling with your app, and that's the easiest way to know.

Comment: Thanks, but what I don't understand is what files make up the soundcloud library.  There is no "soundcloud.py" file in my site-packages folder.  Instead I have the following files "*.py" files:client.py, request.py, resource.py.  I guess part of what I don't understand is what Python is exactly loading when I insert "import soundcloud" into my code.   ---- also I notice that fudge and simplejson are also installed in my site-packages folder locally.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured out.  What I needed to do what copy the soundcloud folder, along with the fudge, simplejson and requests folders into the root folder of my webapp.  Thank you VooDooNOFX -- although you didn't directly answer the precise question, you sparked the thinking that helped me figure it out.